# How to organise the different bits and pieces in an agile environment?

Tags: design, agile, scrum, jira

Trying to make our shop an agile environment, we struggle with some bits and pieces of that world. While not making it waterfally, we do have to have some sort of agreement on what a new feature needs to do. We follow the KISS and "minimally viable product" principle. Still, after discussing a story, we end up with:

- UI/UX design
- Acceptance criteria
- Constraints
- Use cases
- Some extra specifications (like what fields to show in tables etc)

As tools we use JIRA, Greenhopper, Balsamiq, Glyphy and Confluence and they are working very well but we're not quite sure where to store which bits and how to make this work together well.

How do you guys approach that. Please include details on how far you go detailing the feature before development starts.

Comment: It sounds to me like you are focusing so much on the development *process* that you can't see the woods for the trees.  You mention all these tools and how well they are working - and yet you're not progressing because of all these tools.  I myself work in an Agile environment, but when it comes to KISS principles in programming, so should the KISS principle be applied to your business processes.

Comment: Thanks for the input @Moo-Juice, would you mind elaborating in more detail how you apply KISS to your processes and how that is beneficial?

Comment: Your question does not describe the problem that you actually face (which would make it dangerously near to being closed). You've listed a few things that you use in your bespoke development process then asked how to make them work. Umm how would we know? Its your team I don't know what the problems actually are. Can you edit the question and describe the problems - why do you need to change the way you work?

Comment: Is this actually 5 questions? One for each of the bullet points? Maybe consider breaking it up. You might find you get more answers.

Answer (score 2):

When first starting the project, the epic stories go into JIRA OnDemand with little more than a title and perhaps a basic description to allow for prioritization and some very very rough estimation.

Then our product owners start tackling from the top to prepare the stories by filling out acceptance criteria into the description of the story, and attaching any screenshots, PDFs, etc. of wireframes or designs that have been completed for that story directly to the story in JIRA.

At this point, we still are only using the *Plan* view of the Agile board, and haven't created sub-tasks.

Our teams then go through the estimation process to have the story points added to each story.  As estimation and sprint planning occurs, stories may get broken down into multiple smaller stories on the plan board in order to support taking the work into the next sprint.

Once we have a sprint ready, we begin creating the sub-tasks on the stories for the items.  We keep these sub-tasks very light-weight (usually just a title to remind us) but sometimes if the team has some implementation ideas we will add that to the appropriate task.

Our source design files are not kept in JIRA, but in the appropriate design area on our network, or our client's, or DropBox, or wherever is agreed upon for the project.

That's a rough overview of what we are doing, but in direct relation to your list:

- **UI/UX design:** Source files in its own repository, appropriate outputs directly on the stories in JIRA
- **Acceptance criteria:** We had toyed with using sub-tasks for these, but have found that maintaining directly on the story in the description has been easier for tracking.
- **Constraints:** Depending on the constraint, this is either noted directly on the story (if story-specific) or is tracked as its own story that needs to be met with specific development effort and testing (for example, accessibility support).
- **Use Cases:** We keep our test cases/use cases as a special type of sub-task below the story so that the team can easily find all of the cases that will need to be supported and tested, and can also then track progress of completion by moving them through test and completing them.
- **Additional specifications:** We store these directly on the story, if short. If a visual or full spreadsheet is required, these are attached as files on the story.

Answer (score 0):

On UI-heavy stories, we attach PDFs, assets, and other items from the designers directly in the JIRA issue. A discussion tends to develop in the comments section of the issue and its subtasks as constraints, acceptance criteria, and specifications become clarified. We find this is pretty simple and doesn't get in the way too much. Sometimes we even paste content from emails into the issue. The {quote} wrapper works well for this.

Answer (score 0):

What works for me and my company may not work for your (or for others).

We take a pragmatic approach and take the parts of the "development process" that work best for us. Some of these will be agile, some will be waterfall.

On some projects with some clients, some parts of the process will have more emphasis.

Comment: This is the answer :). But it highlights that the question is, "primarily opinion-based" and you should have voted to close :P

Comment: Haha, maybe! I haven't specified one way though over another though, EVERYONE should do this! ;)

Answer (score 0):

This may sound like heresy on a programmers site but I'd advise that you ditch the tools and go manual.

Have a good read of the Scrum Guide (available for free at https://www.scrum.org/Scrum-Guide ) It's only 17 pages long and really easy to understand.

Then try using manual items like index cards for writing user stories, large flat spaces for scrum boards, post-it notes for tasks etc.

If you want a quick start, here's an [article on creating a product backlog](http://www.webgate.ltd.uk/2014/01/create-a-product-backlog/). (Disclosure: This links to an article on my website)

Doing this manually prevents tools from perverting what you're trying to do. Later, with experience, if you *still* want to use a tool, you can bend it to your will, rather than the other way round.

Comment: does the link in your answer refer to **your** blog? http://www.webgate.ltd.uk/2014/01/create-a-product-backlog/ - if yes, consider disclosing your **affiliation** as explained here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94022/how-can-i-link-to-an-external-resource-in-a-community-friendly-way

Comment: @gnat It does indeed. I've added a disclosure statement to my answer.